# How to prevent SQL injection in InfluxDB for a user-supplied measurement

Tags: node.js, influxdb

Say I have an InfluxDB query where the user supplies a measurement. In this case the user supplies the value `"foo"`. Then I would construct the query:

```
SELECT * from "foo"
WHERE time > "2022-06-21T18:27:16.041Z"
```

What's the best way to prevent injection attacks here? I know InfluxDB supports [bind parameters](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#bind-parameters), but apparently that feature only works for the `WHERE` clause, so it wouldn't help me.

I was thinking of trying this:

```
const query = `
  SELECT "value" FROM "${Influx.escape.measurement(key)}"
  WHERE time > "2022-06-21T18:27:16.041Z"
`
```

...but based on my testing that function doesn't escape quotation marks, only spaces.

I'm using InfluxDB 1.x in Node.js via the `influx` npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the value to the query try filtering chars like single and double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Looking into docs, articles I can see that every subquery is in brackets, like:

> select * from (select "value" from "measurement") <where_caluse>

So filtering for brackets beetwen "FROM" and "WHERE" should be enough.

Based on:

#1 https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-january-26-2017/

#2 https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#subqueries

Comment: I think the `<` and `>` brackets are just for tutorial purposes and not valid query syntax. In any case, It seems like filtering for individual characters is a flawed strategy compared to some sort of prepared statement approach.

Comment: Brackets, I mean '(' and ')'. Of course <where_clause> for tutorial. As I said: filter brackets '(' and ')' between "FROM" and "WHERE". Without brackets there cannot be injected subquery.